# Input mask with Ionic 3 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I need to use [**ng2-currency-mask**](https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask) input mask with `Ionic 3` app. They have given a fix for input focus issue which is in the Ionic app. I cannot understand what I have to do here. Can you tell me how to use it?

*child component*

*.html*

```
<div>
    <input currencyMask type="tel" [(ngModel)]="value" [id]="'yourInputId' + index" 
    (focus)="scrollTo(index)" />
</div>
```

*.ts*

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

export class...

    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    scrollTo(index) {
        let yOffset = document.getElementById('yourInputId' + index).offsetTop;
        this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset + 20);
    }
```

Can you tell me what was this `[id]="'yourInputId' + index"`? How can I set that on my Ionic app?

You can read more about [**it here**](https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask#quick-fixes).

**Update:**

I have tried like this.But compile time error on template due to `index`. I don't have any `for loops` here.

```
 <input currencyMask type="tel" [ngModel]="data?.budget" 
 [options]="{ prefix: '', thousands: ',', decimal: '' }" 
 formControlName="budget" 
 ngModelChange)="data.budget=$event;calculateContingency()" 
 [id]="'yourInputId' + index" (focus)="scrollTo(index)"/>
```

**My component structure:**

*parent.html*

```
<ion-content class="project">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="details">
      <project [data]="data"></project>// above code is in this child componet
    </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I am guessing  that yourInputId is a unique code you give to the input tag and index is from ngFor, in case you have one. The whole thing to identify the DOM element by an unique id

Comment: yes the index i think is for a loop array of phones as (home, work, mobile) with the same id but looking like this : ['phone_0', 'phone_1', 'phone_2'] as @Vega said if you have one just put the id name in your input phone. Regards

Comment: Actually, I don't have any `ngFor` here. Just an `input` contol. Then how can I set that? @headmax Please see my update too:

Comment: Please see my **Update** @Vega

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this : (if your input id="mobile")

```
<ion-input currencyMask type="tel" [ngModel]="data?.budget" 
[options]="{ prefix: '', thousands: ',', decimal: '' }" 
formControlName="budget" 
ngModelChange)="data.budget=$event;calculateContingency()" 
[id]="'mobile0'" (focus)="scrollTo(0)"></ion-input>
```

I think the index is an array from phones (home, mobile, work) is about you id name + index (phone).
Setting the id in your context just add 'mobile' and for the index put only 0 for a try i didn't tested that modules. Regards

Comment: I did that. But it shows this error. Any clue? I have scrollTo() method on ts file.  https://i.imgur.com/HjBam37.png

Comment: here the list to setting ion-input https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/ and this is the reason why you need an index

Comment: But they didn't use `ion-input` no? Just an `input` no?

Comment: Try if you can add if you didn't the input list or change <input to <ion-input ..></ion-input> (the scroll method is to focus to the input mobile)

Comment: Now the problem is here `this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset + 20);`. `this.content` shows `undefine` that is why this error? why? https://i.imgur.com/HjBam37.png

Comment: add this at the end (focus)="ionFocus(0)"></ion-input>

Comment: Please see my component structure above. I think that is why I cannot access parent `content` no? How to do that?

Comment: this <ion-input class="project" ... >.. need to be placed in the <ion-row>

Comment: Thanks for the support. But it is not working. May be a component issue. Disappoint :(

Comment: Sorry for that bad support i will try it myself to be aware ;) thanks.

Comment: Nope, You gave very good support. problem with the 3rd party directive. I have logged as an issue : https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask/issues/18#issuecomment-329053852

Comment: ;) hope you got a commit fix soon on git, regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax:

**HTML:**

```
     <ion-input currencyMask type="tel" [ngModel]="data?.budget" 
     [options]="{ prefix: '', thousands: ',', decimal: '' }" 
     formControlName="budget" 
     ngModelChange)="data.budget=$event;calculateContingency()" 
     id="yourInputId" (focus)="scrollTo()"></ion-input>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
 scrollTo() {
        let yOffset = document.getElementById('yourInputId').offsetTop;
        this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset + 20);
    }
```

Comment: Now no errors. But it doesn't allow me to click it since not an `ion-input`. Any clue? But they gave above solution is for that I think. But not working.

Comment: Replace <input> by <ion-input>?

Comment: It shows this error: https://i.imgur.com/HjBam37.png .Please see my component structure above. Due to that, I cannot access parent's `content`. How can I do that? it shows `undefine` here `this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset + 20);`.

Comment: Either 1. set a wrapper on the input and give it a local template variable name #Content 2. Move ...scrollTo to the parent and in the child call it with an output and set #Content on the child tag. I hope being understandable :)

Comment: @viewchild Content is not defined until you set #Content somewhere

Comment: Actually, I do not have `content` class on the child component.Just a `div` element. You can see updated post above. But parent component has. So how can I use `this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset + 20);` method? Hope I don't need `content` here. Any clue?

Comment: Content is a reference to a DOM element with #Content template variable on it which will receive the scroll. It needs to be a wrapper element of the input (thus + 20 on the offset)

Comment: I will make a stackbliz to try to reproduce it

Comment: Yes, You're right. Then can you modify your code to reflect it? Now you know about my component structure.

Comment: My problem here is `this.content` shows `undefine`.

Comment: I am still trying to make the mask work in the demo, but I updated my post

Comment: Thanks. Actually, if you can give me a clue to avoid `this.content` `undefine` issue then I can continue.

Comment: If don't have the issue of the input hidden by the keyboard, you can forgo the (focus)=.... . Otherwise, just putting #Content on the wrapper div, as in my updated post, you should be good. Doesn't it work?

Comment: Did you create an `Ionic 3` project or ?

Comment: I did but the mask dosn't work. Have import { Content } from 'ionic-angular'; ? I haven't seen that before in the doc. And they forgot to add {import ViewChild} from "@angulare/core"

Comment: Do you have <ion-content> ? Content in fact is reference to that element, my bad: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/

Comment: Yes, When I do not use ion-input I cannot click the element. But when I used it then it shows this error. Horrible :( https://i.imgur.com/cROsswH.png

Comment: The same as in my demo :(

Comment: Please see this post too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192659/access-parent-content-within-child-component-or-better-way

Comment: Welcome :) Should you report to the mask writting team? If you need a quick startup: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-pifdy2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I did. But I'll put a new issue with more details later. Thanks. https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask/issues/18#issuecomment-329053852

Comment: I have tried another directive. That too not working with Ionic 3. This is the 2nd day more than 15+ Hours for this simple thing. Sorry for me :( See that too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189208/input-mask-with-thousand-separator-ionic-3

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to make a directive and it seems to work pretty well on desktop, iOS, and android.

#### No hacks required.

create `IonMask` directive by

```
ionic g directive
```

then replace it with this:

```
// Angular
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

// Ionic
import { IonInput } from '@ionic/angular';

// Rxjs
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

// Text-mask
import { createTextMaskInputElement } from 'text-mask-core';

/**
 * ion-mask directive, based on text-mask module
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[ionMask]',
  providers: [IonInput],
})
export class IonMaskDirective {

  @Input('ionMask') 
  private mask            : Array<any>    = [];
  private onDestroy       : Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(public ionInput: IonInput) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.configureInput();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy.next();
  }

  public async configureInput() {
    const input       = await this.ionInput.getInputElement();
    const maskedInput = createTextMaskInputElement({
      inputElement  : input,
      mask          : this.mask,
      guide         : false
    });
    this.ionInput
      .ionChange
      .pipe( takeUntil( this.onDestroy ) )
      .subscribe( ( event: CustomEvent ) => {
        const { value } = event.detail;
        maskedInput.update(value);
        this.ionInput.value = input.value;
      });
  }

}
```

import the directive on your component:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [....],
  declarations: [..., IonMaskDirective , ...],
})
export class yourComponentModule { }
```

Use it like that in your component's template :

```
<ion-input formControlName="controlName" [ionMask]="mask"></ion-input>
```

And in your component's controller (phone mask) :

```
public mask : Array<any>  =  ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/,];
```

source: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/15424#issuecomment-552057007