# Access parent content within child component or better way

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

*parent.html*

```
<ion-content class="project">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="details">
      <project [data]="data"></project>// this child componet
    </ion-row>    
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

*project.html (child)*

```
<input currencyMask type="tel" [ngModel]="data?.budget" 
 [options]="{ prefix: '', thousands: ',', decimal: '' }" 
 formControlName="budget" 
 ngModelChange)="data.budget=$event;calculateContingency()" 
 [id]="'yourInputId' + 0" (focus)="scrollTo(0)"/>
```

*project.ts*

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

    export class ProjectComponent {

        @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

        scrollTo(index) {
            let yOffset = document.getElementById('yourInputId' + index).offsetTop;
            this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset + 20);
        }
}
```

Then it shows below error since `this.content` is `undefine`. Can you tell me how to do it properly?

[image]

Comment: you can inject `Content` into project constructor.

Comment: i guess `document.getElement` returns undefined . if you are getting the content using view child why using viewchild use element ref

Comment: It has value `yOffset = 0`. But next line shows `undefine`. Any clue? @RahulSingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the parent into the child constructor like this :

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

export class ProjectComponent {

    constructor(private content:Content){
    }

    scrollTo(index) {
        let yOffset = document.getElementById('yourInputId' + index).offsetTop;
        this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset + 20);
    }
}
```

But note that now your `ProjectComponent` can only be used inside a `<ion-content>` component. Unless you mark it as `@Optional()` inside the constructor.

Comment: Hope this will inject `new content` class no? But not the already initialized class on `parent content`. Your thoughts?

Comment: It will inject the parent ion-content (`Content` is the class of `ion-content` from what I understand), not a new one.

Comment: Then it would be great. Hope you'll provide a bit more about this injection scenario. Here it is special since parent/ child use case. And my doubt here is you have mentioned it as `private` too. Then how can it be possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: OK, You know that when we inject something here on constructor it creates a new instance of it. How is that behavior different in this scenario? You have mentioned it uses parent's class. So how it happens?

Comment: "You know that when we inject something here on constructor it creates a new instance of it" Sorry but this assumption is false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154321/discussion-between-n00dl3-and-sampath).